# How do I properly convert SVG with custom fonts to PNG with Python and svglib?

Tags: python, css, svg, xml-parsing, png

I have some SVG designs that I am processing with Python. These designs include custom fonts, which I reference using the at-rule `@font-face`. The problem seems to be related to the CSS not being parsed in the SVG. If I didn't have to use custom fonts I would just put all of the style data in their respective elements. Seeing as I have to have some CSS to reference fonts, I would like to find a solution where Python can parse this information properly.

When run, I get the following error (apologies for adding a long traceback):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\main.py", line 215, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\main.py", line 210, in main
    create_svgs(id, primary_name, alt_name, primary_color, secondary_color)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\main.py", line 105, in create_svgs
    save_svg_as_png(file_name)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\main.py", line 113, in save_svg_as_png
    logo = svg2rlg(r'{}\{}.svg'.format(generated_images, file_name))
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 1449, in svg2rlg
    drawing = svgRenderer.render(svg_root)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 545, in render
    main_group = self.renderSvg(node, outermost=True)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 816, in renderSvg
    self.renderG(NodeTracker(def_node))
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 854, in renderG
    item = self.renderNode(child, parent=gr)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 580, in renderNode
    self.renderStyle(n)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 864, in renderStyle
    self.attrConverter.css_rules = CSSMatcher(node.text)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 131, in __init__
    selectors = cssselect2.compile_selector_list(rule.prelude)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect2\compiler.py", line 31, in compile_selector_list  
    return [
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect2\compiler.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    return [
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect2\parser.py", line 38, in parse
    raise exception
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect2\parser.py", line 35, in parse
    yield parse_selector(tokens, namespaces)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect2\parser.py", line 56, in parse_selector
    result, pseudo_element = parse_compound_selector(tokens, namespaces)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\programming\project-folders\svg-zone\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect2\parser.py", line 92, in parse_compound_selector  
    raise SelectorError(peek, 'expected a compound selector, got %s'
cssselect2.parser.SelectorError: (None, 'expected a compound selector, got EOF')
```

Here is the SVG I am trying to process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Design5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" 
     viewBox="0 0 792 493.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 493.2;" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'XXIIDONT-MESS-WITH-VIKINGS-HARDCORE';
                src: url('fonts/XXII DONT MESS WITH VIKINGS.ttf') format('truetype');
            }
            
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'BankGothic-Medium';
                src: url('fonts/bankgthd.ttf') format('truetype');
            }

            .text1 {
                letter-spacing:16;
                font-size:369.1761px;
                font-family:"XXIIDONT-MESS-WITH-VIKINGS-HARDCORE";
            }
            
            .text2 {
                letter-spacing:49;
                font-size:103.7314px;
                font-family:BankGothic-Medium;
            }
            
            .color1 {
                fill: #PrimaryColor;
            }
            
            .color2 {
                fill: #SecondaryColor;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <text id="textLine1-3" textLength='600' lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" transform="matrix(1.3144 0 0 1 0 330)" class="color1 text1">
        primary_name
    </text>
    <text id="textLine2-1" transform="matrix(0.7966 0 0 1 0 412)" class="color2 text2">
        alt_name
    </text>
</svg>
```

And here is the Python code that processes the SVG [(See svglib documentation)](https://pypi.org/project/svglib/):

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF, renderPM

logo = svg2rlg(r'{}\{}.svg'.format(generated_images, file_name))
return renderPM.drawToFile(logo, r'{}\{}.png'.format(generated_images, file_name), fmt='PNG')
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that svglib's dependency, cssselect2, does not handle at-rule CSS parsing (yet). Since I am only using this script locally, I can get away with referencing the font-family in the CSS instead of declaring a font-face.

```
.text1 {
    letter-spacing:16;
    font-size:369.1761px;
    font-family:"XXII DONT-MESS-WITH-VIKINGS HARDCORE";
```

To get the fonts to work properly it is essential to install them on the system and name them correctly in your CSS. I verified the names of each custom font I used in my SVGs by referencing the `C:\Windows\Fonts` directory. If you right click on the font you are referencing and select 'preview', you can see the true name of the font near the top of the window.

I am still having some issues when converting the SVG to a PNG, so it might be worth looking at other SVG packages for Python if you are getting errors after this solution is implemented.